# Picking image from gallery always returns resultCode -1

Tags: android

Here is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(
                intent,
                "Select Image"),
        SELECT_IMAGE_LOCAL);
```

For some reason it is always returning -1. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't -1 the value of RESULT_OK ?

Answer (score 0):

RESULT_OK has a value of -1:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK

Why it is that way is a good question for the android designers... perhaps an internal joke.